# How exactly Kafka built-in retry mechanism work?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to understand Kafka's internal retry mechanism. What exactly does it do when exception occurs? I know that in the end it will call again the KafkaListener. But is it reading again from Kafka or just the KafkaListener is invoked multiple times? Is there any trick on how to get current retry attempt number?